# Unable to change View on event click in full Calendar v4?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have been using FullCalender since couple of weeks, but I'm unable to change month view to list view in FullCalendar V4.

I checked the updated documentation where there is no change view option. Here is my code:

```
 var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [ 'dayGrid','list','interaction' ],
            defaultView:'dayGridMonth',
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
            header:{
                left:'prev,next,today',
                center:'title',
                right:'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,list'
            },
            selectable:true,
            events:newArray,
            eventTextColor:"#ffffff",
            eventRender:function(info){
                info.el.firstChild.innerText=info.event.extendedProps.description;
            },
            eventClick:function(info){

               console.log(info);
            }
    });
    calendar.render();
```

Please help me.

Comment: Hi, Please check this link: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals-demo

Comment: View Source of this page, and check that you have properly included all the needed script files, and follow the pattern of plugins accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is ChangeView option on [This Document Link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-changeView).

Using eventClick, you may call Calendar::changeView as follow:

```
eventClick:function(info){
   calendar.changeView('list', info.event.start); //if single date, if you need date range, please check above link.
}
```